# How can i store visitor infomation like reach time ,duration of visit,and exact location of visitor in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to store visitor information like reach time ,duration of visit and also exact location of the visitor.

Can any one give me any ideas about it? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few links to get you started:

- [JavaScript heat map generator](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html) used to track where users clicked on your site
- [Recording the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893366/web-the-system-will-record-the-length-of-time-the-user-displayed-each-page) a user spent on any single page
- [Tracking the user's location](http://www.damnsemicolon.com/php/php-geolocation-ip-addresses) via IP
- [Official Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) specification

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, best thing would be to use some external website statistics tool (like Google Analytics or similar). You can also search for some solutions you install locally (like AWStats, in case of privacy concerns). No need to reinvent the wheel there.